# Exclude Class/Package from InelliJ auto-import feature

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I work primarily with JavaFX, and do not plan to use Swing or AWT. However, when I type `Button` for the first time in a class, and Intellij auto-imports the class, it often imports `java.awt.Button`, instead of `javafx.scene.control.Button`.

Is there any way to specify a list of packages/classes to not auto-import in Intellij to prevent this behaviour?

I have searched through IntelliJ docs, but cannot find anything relating to this particular issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into "Editor" > "Auto Import" > "Exclude from import and completion".

[image]